# TS-590 Antenna Tuner Protocol

Tags: kenwood, antenna-tuner, remote-control

I'm looking for the protocol used by Kenwood's TS-590S antenna tuner port. I've worked as far as I can with Kenwood's tech support. They know what the pins are labeled, but don't have any information on the protocol used to control the tuner.

Comment: Are you asking about using the Tune button of a TS-590S to control an external tuner?

Comment: If you Google search for the Kenwood AT-300 external tuner service manual you should find sufficient information to discern the operating protocol which is basically the assertion of voltage level on the lines TS and TT.  You could actually put a meter on those lines and measure the asserted voltage itself although this is likely documented.  I have the manual so if you contact me (e-mail good in QRZ.com) I can send it to you.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't think of that. It is in the service manual, but it looks like it basically has three control signals, all simple high/low voltage on 13.7V: tune, abnormal tune, and bypass. It looks like there are no band selection commands. This makes life more complicated for building an interface to my IC-2KL/AT-500, but not impossible. I'll have to have an MCU than collects the signals, polls the radio for frequency over the CAT port, and then sends the control voltage to the Icom equipment. By the way, you should put your solution as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Joseph, these tuning interfaces are not general interfaces for external equipment like band changing on amps and other things of that ilk.  Rather, they are generally used specifically for a remote tuner such as the AT-300.  And, there is no standard that I know of.  ICOM equipment has their own antenna tuner interface and it too is simple with different voltage levels on signal lines but it is designed for their tuner (like the AH-4 for example).  If you want band changing protocol, that is usually offered separate from the Tuner interface on many rigs via their accessory port.

Comment: The IC-2KL and AT-500 have a reference voltage of 8v and a step voltage that switches the tuner and amp together when they are on 'Auto'. The reason I'm keen on making them interface directly to the radio is because I have an American version of the amp. The switch has no setting for the 10-12 meter filter and there is no European replacement due to age, so even if I install the correct filter I can't use it on 10-12m. It will, however, switch to 10-12 with the auto-switching feature, so if I am able to create an adapter then I can install the filter and use the amp on all bands.